# Bitrise Runs Deployment Workflow on Code Push (when it shouldn't)

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, bitrise

I am confused why the following 2 things happen:

1. When I push some commits to my `feature_foo` branch, 2 workflows (builds) are run: the primary workflow against the latest commit, and deploy workflow against *my last PR*, both on `feature_foo`. I expected only the primary workflow to be run as I haven't issued a PR yet
2. 2 identical email notifications are sent to me from `artifacts+\<my-bitrise-project-id\>@bitrise.io` within the same minute. I understand that a PR [can lead to two builds](https://devcenter.bitrise.io/builds/triggering-builds/trigger-map/#dont-start-two-builds-for-pull-requests-from-the-same-repository) (as a PR is technically a push), but doubt that is the issue here as I've not created a PR yet.

Here is my current bitrise.yml trigger map:

```
trigger_map:
- push_branch: "*"
  workflow: primary
- pull_request_source_branch: "*"
  pull_request_target_branch: feature
  workflow: deployment-staging
- tag: "v*.*.*"
  workflow: deployment-production
```

By the way, this is my desired 3-workflow setup:

1. Run integration tests (primary workflow) on 2 occasions:

   1. Code push to * (any branch)
   2. Pull requests to `feature` branch (when the PR is created i.e. pre-merged state so contributors can preview the potential effect of their proposed changes)
2. Run deployment (deploy workflow) to **staging** when **PRs from * to `feature` branch are merged**
3. Run deployment (deploy workflow) to **production** when **tags `v*.*.*` are pushed**

What is the correct bitrise.yml config to achieve this? The [docs](https://devcenter.bitrise.io/builds/triggering-builds/trigger-map/) do not indicate how we can differentiate PRs by state (issued vs merged). I want to deploy only *after the code has been reviewed*.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open the PR will that trigger another build? Are you sure the PR isn't opened yet?

To answer

> I want to deploy only after the code has been reviewed.

I guess you mean when the PR is reviewed **and merged** into the target branch e.g. into `master`.

For that you can use a config like this: https://devcenter.bitrise.io/builds/triggering-builds/trigger-map/#dont-start-two-builds-for-pull-requests-from-the-same-repository

```
trigger_map:
- push_branch: master
  workflow: deploy
- pull_request_target_branch: "*"
  workflow: primary
```

This will run a build using the workflow called `primary` when you open the PR and every time you update the PR. Typically you want to run some automated tests in this case, in the `primary` workflow (unit/ui tests, linters and/or doing maybe a test build).

Then when you merge the PR (in this case into the `master` branch) it'll trigger a build using the `deploy` workflow (as technically a merge generates a commit/push event).

I hope this helps, let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 1):

Viktor's answer is sufficient, but I wanted to add some more findings that might be relevant to someone else:

> When I push some commits to my feature_foo branch, 2 workflows (builds) are run: the primary workflow against the latest commit, and deploy workflow against my last PR, both on feature_foo

I believe this happened because I had an open PR and pushed additional commits to the source branch of that PR. Based on my trigger map (shared above on the OP) at that time, it would run a `deploy-staging` workflow. The trigger map shared by Viktor makes more sense for my use case

> 2 identical email notifications are sent to me from artifacts+\@bitrise.io within the same minute

Turns out Bitrise sends both a signed and an unsigned APK (for whatever) in two separate emails